# Impossible to adjust the range of a NumberLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to display a value on a fixed range say [0,2].

```
NumberLinePlot[.2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: result]

```
NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: result]

Mathematica tries to guess the best range to display, so it zooms in on [0,1] for the small value and zooms out to [0,4] for the large one, which is natural.

To freeze the range displayed, I tried adding various option even though they are not listed as a possible option in the documentation. The result is ... unexpected as `PlotRange` shrinks to [0,1], `PlotRegion` zooms out to [0,4]
and `RegionFunction` is not accepted:

```
NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image: result]

```
NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRegion -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

Any idea on how to impose the range to [0,2] ? My ultimate goal is to make a dynamic slider but with a range that does not jumps around when x changes which is currently the case if I try :

```
Manipulate[NumberLinePlot[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Thanks.

PS. I am using Mathematica 11.3 on MacOS 10.13.4.

Comment: does `Show[NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}], PlotRange->{{0,2},All}]` work?

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying. It seems that on v11.3 the only way to answer my question is to pass the `PlotRange` option to `Show` as in @kglr answer below. I will validate this one but I am glad to know they might fix the bug in the next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Show[NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, All}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Also works with v11.3 on a Mac (thanks: @Bob Hanlon).

Answer (score 1):

You need to state that `{0, 2}` refers to the x-range. By default, listing one range refers to the y-range.

```
NumberLinePlot[1.9, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

---

### Edit

This method does not work in 11.3, but works in older versions and appears to be fixed for the next version already.

Comment: With v11 .3 on a Mac, with this code the number line shown is the interval {0, 1} and the point is not shown (it is outside the displayed interval).

Comment: Oh interesting. This seems to only be an issue for 11.3. I just tried 11.1, 11.2, and the current 12.0 prototype and they all work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 NumberLinePlot[x, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: With v11.3 on a Mac, for this code the number line is fixed on the interval {0, 1} and the right half of the Manipulate control does not display the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```
$Version
(*"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"*)

NumberLinePlot[x == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 0}}]

NumberLinePlot[x == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]

NumberLinePlot[x == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> Full]

NumberLinePlot[x == 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[NumberLinePlot[y == x, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue], {x, 0, 2}]
```